# Where is the SDK for DirectX on Win10?

Tags: c++, graphics, direct3d

I was just told that the SDK that I was using (Jun 2010) is not to be used anymore and that I need to use whatever new one they have included to Win10. Well where is it?

I am trying to start a graphics demo solution and I can't call D3D11 functions because of Linker errors which to me means I need to include libraries and such.

If anyone can help me figure this out so I can get the ball rolling then I'll be good.

Comment: I found openGL with freeglut was more intuitive to learn

Comment: @Charlie maybe... but all the jobs Ive been looking at want DirectX experience... I used it in school but it was the old SDK like I said.... I know OpenGL is good to know, I just really want to do DirectX

Comment: Literally the first search result on Google: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/

Comment: That doesnt answer what I need though... I dont mind if Im using Dx12 or 11 but I cant find anywhere that tells you where any libraries and includes are so that I can actually code and call functions.....

Comment: There is no separate SDK anymore, it was integrated into the Windows SDK a while ago.  You can only get help with linker errors when you post the linker error message.

Comment: Fair Enough @HansPassant 


Error LNK2019  unresolved external symbol _D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@48 referenced in function "long __cdecl InitDevice(void)" (?InitDevice@@YAJXZ) Dx11Engine Z:\BellaWork\Dx11Engine\Dx11Engine\main.obj 1 

Create Device and Swap chain is like the most needed function... so I feel like that is because the libraries are messed up or something...

Comment: Just google "D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain" and take the first hit, it takes you to the MSDN article for the function.  The bottom of the article list which .h file you have to include, which you got right, and which .lib file you have to link, which you appear to not got right.  So use Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies setting, add "d3d11.lib"

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft Doc page [Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) tells you to use the Windows SDK, specifically the Windows 8.0 SDK, Windows 8.1 SDK, or Windows 10 SDK to do DirectX development (which is assumed to be Direct3D 11 or Direct2D/DirectWrite). Direct3D 12 requires the Windows 10 SDK.

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 or later, then you already have the Windows 8.1 SDK and optionally the Windows 10 SDK.

An important detail is that the D3DX library (D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11) is deprecated and only available in the legacy DirectX SDK. That means D3DX11 is not part of the Windows SDK, and you shouldn't use it.

> **UPDATE**: For older projects, the legacy DirectX SDK 'end-of-life' June 2010 release of the D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 library is provided in [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) which is to be combined with the Windows 10 SDK. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) for the full details.

For HLSL, you use [D3DCompile](https://walbourn.github.io/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/) directly or the FXC that comes with the Windows SDK. For math, you use [DirectXMath](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/) that comes with the Windows SDK. If you are using legacy Effects 11, you can use the version from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11). I recommend you also take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and it's [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). For a complete list of replacements for D3DX, see [Living without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).

> If you really want to continue to use the legacy DirectX SDK components with Visual Studio 2012 or later, you can but you should note the details at the bottom of the MSDN page above. Notably you have to reverse the include/lib path order when you add the legacy DirectX SDK to your project.

For a complete catalog of where the various bits of the old DirectX SDK ended up, see [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdks-of-a-certain-age/), [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-tools-catalog/), [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-sdk-samples-catalog/), as well as the *Living without D3DX* article above.

> The Direct3D 11 Debug Device for Windows 10 is not installed by any Windows SDK or by the legacy DirectX SDK. It is a windows optional feature. See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks/).
>
> The actual "DirectX Runtime" has been part of the operating system since Windows XP Service Pack 2. The legacy DirectX SDK never installs "DirectX" on any modern version of Windows, and only deploys some optional side-by-side stuff. It's not required at all if you using the Windows SDK. See [Not So Direct Setup](https://walbourn.github.io/not-so-direct-setup/).